# Wordpress 3.8.3. custom theme - sliders won't load js/css files

Tags: plugins, themes, javascript

I'm building custom WP theme and I have issues with sliders. None of those I've tried to install worked. When I looked into the developers console, and searched for their js/css files, they where not there. Not in the header or the footer. One of those plugins had option to include his files into header or footer - tried to change that but didn't work. Contact form and pagenavi are working just fine, but sliders not. There are no js errors, because there are no files to cause them. WP version is 3.8.3. jQuery 1.9.3 is included and working fine. Am I missing something in my functions.php ( theme is made from scratch ) maybe?

Comment: Without code, we have no way to help you. How is jQuery 1.9.3 loaded, when WordPress uses version 1.10 (in WordPress 3.8)?

Comment: I added it manually, should I remove it and use the one from WP?

Comment: Yes. Always use core-bundled scripts; *especially* jQuery - and *especially* when you're experiencing problems getting jQuery-related scripts to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The issue was in wp_head and wp_footer. That's what you get when you work 12 hours in a row with WP :).

Answer (score 0):

As [Chip](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/3966/chip-bennett) notes in the comments: alway use the jquery bundled with WP. When you are developing your own theme, always make sure `wp_head` and `wp_footer` are present.

Plugins assume you are following these standards and will make sure their sliders or whatever work with them. Using other versions of jquery essentially means the slider scripts becomes untested and may not work.